# Forms Authentication adding additional information along with ReturnUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, forms-authentication

With Forms Authentication when the app needs to redirect to sign-in page is there an event or any extensibility point that will let me do additional work to the request before it redirects to the sign-in page?

I would like to send additional information in the query string that could vary such that it wouldn't work to just statically embed that in the link in the loginUrl node in the web.config.

**Edit:** For clarification, I want to intercept the request prior to being redirected **TO the login** page.

**Example:**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="http://the/interwebs/login.aspx" timeout="2880" 
                enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
</authentication>
```

And prior the user being redirected to http://the/interwebs/login.aspx I would like to be able to pack in query values so the url could end up something like http://the/interwebs/login.aspx?Action=Refresh

Comment: How do you handle the redirect today? By code or by Web.config -> authorisation?

Comment: Using the loginUrl value in the web.config, does this all have to be done in a custom http module?

Comment: You might need to put code in Begin_Request (Global.asax), to work out if this request is to the login page as a result of a request to a secure page (check url and QS), then append on your values in the QS. By the way - what is the 'additional information' you would like to send, maybe we can think of a workaround.

Comment: One is an action message where the most normal value is SignIn, I also need the return url to be the absolute path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before with an http module. My example (stripped down), in vb.net. I'm just checking for a 401 status code and doing my own redirect. The big trick here was that I had to remove and add back the web.config httpModules to make sure my httpmodule stepped in from of the url authorization module. In my case I had some url rewriting for localization, and I needed to send the locale ID to the login page as it was lost by the normal redirect in the url authorization module. I made heavy use of Reflector to build up the base path (not shown), as these are private methods.

```
    Public Sub Init(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpApplication) Implements System.Web.IHttpModule.Init
        AddHandler context.EndRequest, AddressOf Context_EndRequest
    End Sub

    Private Sub Context_EndRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        If TypeOf sender Is HttpApplication Then

            Dim hApplication As HttpApplication = DirectCast(sender, HttpApplication)
            Dim hContext As HttpContext = hApplication.Context

            If (hContext.Response.StatusCode = &H191) Then

                hContext.Response.Redirect(String.Format("{0}?ReturnUrl={1}&someparam2={2}", basepath, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(hContext.Request.RawUrl), someparam2))

            End If

        End If

    End Sub
```

**web.config changes**

```
  <httpModules>
      <clear/>
      <!-- custom -->
      <add name="SomeHttpModule" type="SomeCompany.SomeProduct.SomeHttpModule"/>
      <!-- add back defaults, exlude PassportAuthentication, AnonymousIdentification, Profile -->
      <add name="OutputCache" type="System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule"/>
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
      <add name="WindowsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsAuthenticationModule"/>
      <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule"/>
      <add name="RoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule"/>
      <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule"/>
      <add name="FileAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule"/>
  </httpModules>
```

Comment: Seeing as I recently cracked open FormsAuthentication in reflector this code seems to be the most accurate solution for handling this.

Comment: I really can't believe someone DV'd this post when it's the exact answer.

Comment: I was surprised as well - would have been nice if the downvoter left a comment.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic: when I copy ScottE's code, I'm not able to capture the request before the login, I always get code `200` or `302` . Could you post the code you ended up using for your use case?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this via handling the event [HttpApplication.AuthenticateRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.authenticaterequest.aspx)

```
    private void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {

        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;

        string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
        HttpCookie authCookie = context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

        if (authCookie == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(authCookie.Value))
        {
            //... do something
        }
```

FYI, We currently do this via an IHttpModule implementation.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to use the Forms authentication's mechanism to redirect people to a URL. You can do that in code. Just [sign them in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx) and Redirect them yourself using `Response.Redirect`.

Comment: He's not talking about RedirectFromLoginPage, he's talking about the built in code to redirect TO the login page (which ASP.NET handles automatically, as part of the web.config setting)

Comment: Yes RPM is correct this is what my question pertains to, I need to change what happens to feed the Login page, not vice-a-versa.