# Add additional parameter in URL along with ReturnUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I am using Asp.NET Forms authentication for my project. When the authentication cookie expires, Forms authentication redirects to `loginUrl`, and appends `ReturnUrl` parameter in query string.

Eg `http://localhost:1234/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=/blabla`

Now, I want to add a parameter `Id`, to this url, such as:

`http://localhost:1234/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=/blabla&Id=123`

Where the value for `Id` should be fetched from code behind.

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919495/forms-authentication-adding-additional-information-along-with-returnurl), but it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

FormsAuthentication simply redirects to the login page with a ReturnUrl parameter value of whatever the last request was.  I'm not sure what '..it doesn't solve my problem' means, but the article you link to, for creating an Http Module, seems to be your best bet.  In other words, you'll have to put some custom code between the detection of the user not being authenticated and the redirect to the login page.  The clean ways to do this are described in that article.